# How do I declare an MVC 5 action like in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In Web Api I usually declare actions like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(MyModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int accountId)
    {
      //get myModel

        return Ok(myModel);
    }
```

I like the request being passed in rather obtaining it from the controller.  Does MVC do something like that?  I have been searching but cant find any examples or references to this ability.

edit:  Also, I would like to return an interface.  Basically I am looking for something like this in MVC:

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(MyModel))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int accountId)
    {
      //get myModel

        return View(myModel);
    }
```

Comment: Web API was based on MVC, the syntax works in both cases. Have you tried something and found a problem ?

Comment: Isn't the request passed in being the *view* itself?  Normally you would be POSTing a form, unless you're doing something AJAXy.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It seems IHttpActionResult is only available for Web API?  Is there a generic type I can return for MVC or is ActionResult it?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do in MVC?  It would seem that you're trying to do WebAPI in MVC, which is using MVC in the wrong way.  MVC is focused on a different workflow, and thus works differently.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to send over the wire? HTML or some serialized data to deserialize on your client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit different with MVC, `Actions` map to user interactions, not directly to a HttpRequest as such. They are designed to pass in a `Model` and respond with a `View()`. You typically dont need to check things like headers and method type because what you need is part of the method parameters.
If you need a `View` to be a for a specific method type, you can decorate it with `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]` etc.

You can get the current HttpContext via the static property `HttpContext.Current.HttpRequest` directly from the controller action itself easily enough

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed to know.  Is ActionResult the currently accepted return object?  Or is there an interface I could return instead?

Comment: @Mike_G - You ran return almost anything, but the framework will wrap it in a ContentResult if it's not an ActionResult.  (ContentResult is derived from ActionResult, as is ViewResult, JsonResult, FileResult, etc..).  In MVC6 they add IActionResult as an option as well, but that's not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you defying all those extra things, you can just simply return JSON of your object if needed to use it with Ajax. Decorate the Method with `[HttpPost]` is you want Post only.

```
// Home/Get/1 (use `id` in the constructor parameter)
// Home/Get/?accountID=1 (anything other than `id` in the constructor)
public JSONResult Get(int id)
{  
     //To get the Current Request, just start typing Request
    Request.Browser();
    MyModel myModel = Get.MyModel(id);
    return JSON(myModel, allowget);
}
```

Using it as a Task and Post. I am still not sure why we need to this but OK.

```
// FormVariable "accountID=1&userID=23"
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JSONResult> Get(int accountID, int userID)
{  
     //To get the Current Request, just start typing Request
    Request.Browser();
    MyModel myModel = await Get.MyModel(id);
    return JSON(myModel);
}
```

Comment: Yea, whatever, I never use that anyway :) as you can tell. Updated.